# Calculator malfunction

Tags: calculator

my calculator is set to degree but when I do sin(pi) it gives me the answer as 0.054804 which is weird because the answer is obviously 0 in both DEG and RAD

Comment: In degree $\sin(\pi)$ is just $\sin(3.1\dots)$.  In degree, $\sin(x) = 0$ implies that $x = k180$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Woooooow I feel stupid haha thanks

Comment: User error, not calculator error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, but remember that $\pi \mathrm{\: rad}=180^{\circ}$, so $\sin(\pi^{\circ}) \neq \sin(\pi \: \mathrm{rad})$. $\sin(\pi)=\sin(180^{\circ})=0$. Check that your calculator is in RAD, not in DEG nor GRAD.